# How to implement class that supports circular iteration and deletion

Tags: scala

I have a class, that should support circular iteration and deletion:

```
class CircularTest {

    private val set = mutable.LinkedHashSet[String]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    private val circularIter: Iterator[String] = Iterator.continually(set).flatten

    def selectNext: String = {
      circularIter.next()
    }

    def remove(v: String): Unit = {
      set.remove(v)
    }
  }
```

And this not working.

Simple test, that should work:

```
val circularTest = new CircularTest

circularTest.selectNext shouldEqual "1"
circularTest.selectNext shouldEqual "2"

circularTest.remove("3")
circularTest.remove("5")

circularTest.selectNext shouldEqual "4" // actual "3"
circularTest.selectNext shouldEqual "1"
```

How to implement this functionality? Or maybe other solution with no iterator?

Comment: Updating an iterator.... That is profound indeed. In this particular case... you will have to declare the `circularIterator` as `var` and then add `circularIter = Iterator.continually(set).flatten` line to remove method.

Comment: It's fairly clear why it's not going to work. Although iterators are lazy, in order to return the 1 and 2, the `continually` has to have produced one complete set in order for `flatten` to work on it. So the `3` is already "done" and removing `3` from the set will only take effect when that first set is exhausted. You could do this by having `.next` explicitly do the. `continually` and `flatten` and  `remove` remove it from any "pending" items as well as the set itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... The thing is that the `Iterator.continually` will give you a kind of immutable thing in this case. Which means that even if you change the content of your set it will have no effect on iterator.

You can actually have a work around that with updating the iterator itself in the remove method.

```
class CircularTest {

  private var set = Set[String]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

  private var circularIter: Iterator[String] = Iterator.continually(set).flatten

  def selectNext: String = this.synchronized {
    circularIter.next()
  }

  def remove(v: String): Unit = this.synchronized {
    set = set.remove(v)
    circularIter = Iterator.continually(set).flatten
  }
}
```

But a better approach is to actually implement your own iterator in proper way.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class MyCircularIterator[T] extends Iterator[T] {

  private var index: Int = 0
  private var set: mutable.LinkedHashSet[T] = mutable.LinkedHashSet()
  private var vector: Vector[T] = Vector()
  private var vectorSize: Int = 0


  override def hasNext: Boolean = this.synchronized {
    set.size match {
      case 0 => false
      case _ => true
    }
  }

  // Iterator does not define `next()` behavior whe hasNext == false;
  // here it will just throw IndexOutOfBoundsException
  override def next(): T = this.synchronized {
    index = index % vectorSize
    val next = vector(index)
    index = index + 1
    next
  }

  def add(t: T*): Unit = this.synchronized {
    set = set ++ t
    vector = Vector(set.toList: _*)
    vectorSize = vector.length
  }

  def remove(t: T*): Unit = this.synchronized {
    set = set -- t
    vector = Vector(set.toList: _*)
    vectorSize = vector.length
  }

}

object MyCircularIterator {

  def apply[T](hashSet: HashSet[T]): MyCircularIterator[T] = {
    val iter = new MyCircularIterator[T]()
    iter.add(hashSet.toList: _*)
    iter
  }

}
```

Now you can use it like this,

```
val myCircularIterator = MyCircularIterator(HashSet[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

myCircularIterator.next()
// 1
myCircularIterator.next()
// 2
myCircularIterator.remove(3, 5)
myCircularIterator.next()
// 4
myCircularIterator.next()
// 1
```

Comment: Thanks, note that with first "bad" solution, also need save current pointer to element and restore it after iterator's initialisation. I can edit your implementation to replace `HashSet ` with `mutable.LinkedHashSet`, to get it work.